# Preventing Excel from altering my CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, csv

We have a program that exports reports as CSV files. When they are downloaded, they are all seperated by column.

I have written a macro that adds a formula to this CSV file to return a value "DECIMAL" if the £ value in a specific cell is not £1 or £1.00 (i.e. 0.01-0.99).

I then copy the results within the macro, and paste them back in as text only.

When I save my CSV file and then reopen it, everything is concatenated into column A rather than A-N as it was.

Why is this? It is preventing another macro of mine from running as it looks in the specific columns for data. As shown below, it is using c10 and c11.

```
Cells(x + 2, y).FormulaR1C1 = "=countifs('week " & x & ".csv'!c10,R2C&""*"", 'week " & x & ".csv'!c11, " & string1 & " )"
```

To clarify - when saved the CSV is 100% Text only

Can i work around this?

Comment: Please show the code of your first macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the csv you need to use a special macro to add again the delimiter.

Please remember that when you open, for example, a comma separated csv using the "Convert to columns wizard" and in the same workbook you try to open a tab-separated csv, excel try to find the comma delimiter (the first setting for delimiter) and because this time is a different delimiter he is not able to separate each column and write all columns in the first one.

I give you another explanation: when I open a comma separated csv file in excel all columns are correctly separated . After that,I copy the result grid of a query from sql management to excel and all data are concatenated in the first column because sql return a grid that is tab separated.

So in your macro you have first of all correctly create a new csv with the correct delimiter.

Comment: Perfect answer thank you, this 100% solved my issue :)